# Why OnMouseDown, Drag, Up not work in unity2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, gameobject

I created 2d project. And functions
OnMouseDown() ,OnMouseDrag() ,OnMouseUp() do not work.

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    Debug.Log ("MOUSE DOWN");
}

void OnMouseDrag() {
    typeBtnPos = typeBtn [typeSquare].transform.position;

    typeBtn [typeSquare].transform.position = new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

    Debug.Log ("MOUSE");
}

void OnMouseUp() {
    typeBtn [typeSquare].transform.position = typeBtnPos;

    Debug.Log ("MOUSE UP");
}
```

Comment: Are you calling these anywhere?

Comment: In main class, at the end.

Comment: try this for the first one and see if it helps: 
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){Debug.Log("MOUSE DOWN");}  if so can you post full code showing implementation?

Comment: good idea:) thx))))

Comment: Some tips: make sure that your object has a collider, and that no other objects with a collider are on the way (like a Raycast, OnMouseDown "takes" the first object on the way).